# score-function=reciprocal seems to be not working Marklogic 9-0-9.1

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

score-function option in  cts:element-range-query seems to be not working in marklogic version 9.0-9.1. but it is working in marklogic version 8.

To test check this, inserted few documents in document database using insert query:

```
xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml", <rating>1</rating>, (), "temp"),
xdmp:document-insert("/test2.xml", <rating>2</rating>, (), "temp"),
xdmp:document-insert("/test3.xml", <rating>3</rating>, (), "temp"),
xdmp:document-insert("/test4.xml", <rating>4</rating>, (), "temp")
```

added element range index for element "rating" to document database

```
cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("","rating"), "<=", xs:int("4"), ("score-function=reciprocal"), 2))
```

result from ML 9.0-9.1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>1</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>3</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>2</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>4</rating>
```

result from ML 8.0-4.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>4</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>3</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>2</rating>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rating>1</rating>
```

Did anyone notice this difference?
Is there anything that I am missing here.

Any suggestion would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bug. Check what the actual scores there are, I expect that they maybe fall into the same bucket and end up as the same value now. There was a bug in ML8 where the default scaling did not line up with the documented ranges for certain datatypes. You workaround is to use a slope factor of 1/8.

Comment: I assume your document inserts are typos, because you have no rating element in them.

Comment: Thanks !! It seems that it works with slope factor in ML version 9. the search result order gets changes after adding slope-factor=20.  But there still difference search result order - it is not exactly the same as we are getting in previous ML version 8.  Is this is some kind of improvement that is added to ML 9